# Prime Numbers in C

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, primes, break

FIRST PROGRAM

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n,c;
    printf("enter a numb");
    scanf( "%i", &n);

    for( c = 2; c <= n; c++){
        if( n % c == 0 )
            break;
    }

    if( c == n )
        printf("\nprime\n");
    else
        printf("\nnot prime\n");
    getchar();
}
```

SECOND PROGRAM

```
#include "stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a Number\n");
    int in, loop, rem, chk;
    scanf("%d",&in);

    for ( loop = 1; loop <= in; loop++){
        rem = in % loop;
        if( rem == 0)
            chk = chk +1;
    }
    if ( chk == 2 )
        printf("\nPRIME NUM ENTERED\n");
    else
    printf("\nNUM ENTERED NOT PRIME\n");
    getchar();
}
```

The 2nd program works, but the first one was the one my friend wrote, and the program looks fine but on checking it by stepping into we found that the `if` condition in first program is coming true under every input so whats the logical error here please help me found out......

Comment: No comments on the inefficient algorithm: your `scanf()` needs the *address* of `n` (i.e. `&n`), not `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're talking about the first program, there is a problem with how you read the integer n. You need to pass its address:

```
printf("enter a numb");
scanf("%i",&n);
```

I'm surprised that your compiler doesn't catch this.

Comment: +1: It surely did, but as a warning, which are *so* attended to these days. `-Wall -Werror` ftw.

Answer (score 2):

this condition is wrong in the first one:

```
       for(c=2;c<=n;c++)
```

You have to go untill n/2. In your case the condition is always true because when c == n then n % c is equal to 0 and you reach the break.

The definition of a prime number is that its only divisors are 1 and itself.

so the correct for statement is :

```
for (c = 2; c < = n / 2; c++)
```

EDIT:

In fact, there should be no more divisors after you reach trunc(sqrt(n)).

```
     for (c=2; c < trunc(sqrt(n)) c++)
```

Comment: The program returns "prime" if n==c; even though this is not efficient, it is correct.

Comment: Placing some faith in the optimizer to const-expr-out that `trunc(sqrt(n))` from repeated re-eval too, i c.

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is correct.
The problem is in your scanf statement...You need to pass the address of the variable.
It should be : `scanf("%i",&n);`